# Why my Hugo theme host on GitHub Page lost css style?

Tags: html, css, git, github-pages, hugo

Here is my GitHub page:
http://cecilialee.github.io

Here are the source files:
https://github.com/cecilialee/cecilialee.github.io
https://github.com/cecilialee/cecilialee-source

I'm trying to set up a Hugo blog on my GitHub page. I followed the instruction here: https://gohugo.io/themes/installing-and-using-themes/

However, after I use `hugo` to build the site in `public` (in `cecilialee-source`) and push `public` to `https://github.com/cecilialee/cecilialee.github.io`, the site just doesn't work. The Hugo site is there, but it lost all the css styles.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the rendered HTML that your site returns.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cecilialee.github.iocss/style.css">`

In particular, note that there is a missing `/` between `github.io` and `css/` on each occurrence.

Additionally, I noticed that your site is being served over **HTTPS** and that these links are looking for **HTTP** references. 
To fix this, you'll need to define your base URL with `https://`.

If you have not yet looked into developer tools for your browser of choice, I'd highly recommend it. There's documentation available for each browser - [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) describes it for Google Chrome.

Opening developer tools generally points out errors like this.

Comment: Oh my god you fixed my night! I can sleep now!

Comment: You're welcome - sometimes it's the simple things that catch us out!